# HTML datalist keeps crashing when dynamically loaded with Vue

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js, vuejs2, html-datalist

I'm using Vue.js to load an HTML datalist. Whenever I type in my input box that is connected to my datalist, my page freezes (using Chrome). I'm using jQuery to make an AJAX call to initially get all of my users when the page loads, then using the JavaScript filter function to make a new array that has `indexOf` whatever is typed in my input box, then putting that new filtered array of objects into the datalist element.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div id="my-app">
  <input list="user-search" type="text" id="find-user" name="find-user" v-model="findUser">
    <datalist id="user-search">
      <option v-for="user in findUserList">{{ user.vendorName }}</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

**Here is my Vue JavaScript:**

```
var myApp = new Vue({
  el: '#my-app',
  data: {
    users: [],
    findUser: '',
    findUserList: '',
  },
  watch: {
    findUser: function(val) {
      this.findUserResults();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    findUserResults: function() {
      var lookFor = this.findUser.toLowerCase();
      this.findUserList = this.users.filter(function(user) {
        return (user.vendorName.toLowerCase().indexOf(myApp.findUser.toLowerCase()) > -1 || user.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(myApp.findUser.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      });
    },
    loadUsers: function() {
      $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/users',
        success: function(data) {
          myApp.users = JSON.parse(data);
        },
        error: function() {
                console.log('error...');
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.loadUsers();
  }
})
```

The users load fine when the page loads. No problems there. I even commented out the `v-for` and just `console.log`'d the results of the filter with no problem either. The issue comes in when I implement dynamically adding the `<option>` values in the `<datalist>`. I've tried wrapping the options in the vue `<template>` tag and moving the `v-for` there with no success.

I have this working fine on another page, but instead I'm populating a table with `<tr>` and `<td>` instead of `<datalist>` and `<option>`.

What could be causing my page to crash? Is `<datalist>` not good enough to handle all of this? Maybe I'm missing something that a second set of eyes could help solve.

**EDIT**

The data that is being populated into `users` looks like this (it's an array of objects):

```
[{id:1, vendorName:'john'}, {id:2, vendorName:'Rachel', {id:3, vendorName:'Steve'}]
```

**ANSWER**

This was actually just an example of someone overthinking (me). B.Fleming's answer about this being recursive clued me into why my approach above was incorrect. There is no need to keep reloading the datalist options every time the user types. That's exactly what `<datalist>` being linked to `<input>` does; no JavaScript needed. All I need(ed) to do was load all ~3,000 of my users into the `<datalist>` tag as `<option>`s on page load (or whenever I want the input and datalist to show up), and let the datalist and input handle the rest. I haven't tested this with the app in the example above because I'm not near that computer, but just as a proof of concept that a datalist can handle thousands of option elements, I wrote this and ran it locally with no issue (not sure why the snippet console keeps saying there is an error when it works):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var datalistElement = document.getElementById('datalist-test');
    var datalistString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
        datalistString += '<option>' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7); + '</option>';
    }
    datalistElement.innerHTML = datalistString;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Datalist Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <input list="datalist-test" type="text">
 <datalist id="datalist-test">
 </datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

3,000 datalist option elements, and it's fine.

Comment: What is `manageAlertsApp`?

Comment: @Bert sorry. That was supposed to be changed to `myApp`. Fixed.

Comment: Can you show some sample data of what is returned for users?

Comment: @Bert I updated my original post with sample data.

Comment: hey, have you considered some debounce behavior + pagination ? Also, how many users do you initially pull in before you key-up ?

Comment: @82Tuskers around 3,000 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinitely recursive calls. You're calling `myApp.findUser()` on entering/deleting search text, which calls `myApp.findUserResults()`, which calls `myApp.findUser()`, etc. You'll need to fix this.

To fix this, all you have to do is load all of the users into the datalist options once. Then, let the input box and datalist handle the rest. No need to keep reloading the datalist options every time the user types.

Comment: findUser in the `watch` section of my Vue app is not necessarily a function. It's referring to the `findUser` variable under data. It's Vue's version of an event listener.

Comment: Hm... now that I think about it though, it might be messing with the values of the datalist and how that relates to the input that is binded to `findUser`.

Comment: This actually lead me to solve this issue. All I needed to do was load all of my option values into the datalist on page load. No need to keep re-creating the object that is binded to the datalist option for loop.

Comment: Edited this answer with more detail so it could be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) for this. I also made a few other changes. For one, referencing the Vue itself from inside it is a bad practice; just use `this`. Also datalist options have a value property that you need to specify.

```js
console.clear()

const users = [
  {vendorName: "Vendor One", email: "bob@example.com"},
  {vendorName: "Vendor Two", email: "mary@example.com"},
  {vendorName: "Vendor Three", email: "jim@example.com"},
  {vendorName: "Vendor Four", email: "joe@vendor.com"},
  {vendorName: "Vendor Five", email: "sara@vendor.com"},
  
]
var myApp = new Vue({
  el: '#my-app',
  data: {
    users: [],
    findUser: '',
  },
  computed:{
    vendors(){
      return this.users.filter(u => {
        return u.vendorName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.findUser) > -1 ||
          u.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.findUser) > -1
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadUsers: function() {
      // obviously, this is different for example purposes
      this.users = users
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.loadUsers();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="my-app">
  <h3>Type "V"</h3>
  <input list="user-search" name="find-user" v-model="findUser">
  <datalist id="user-search">
    <option v-for="user in vendors" :value="user.vendorName">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: How does computed change, though? Does computed act like an event listener as well? How does it know when `findUser` changes?

Comment: @aCarella Whenever any value that Vue is observing referenced inside the computed property changes, the computed property will be re-calculated. This is part of the "magic" of Vue. In this case, if either `findUser` or `users` changes, the computed property will automatically update.

Comment: I just tried to implement this, but it is still crashing my browser. It's about ~2,500 results after the first key up. Not sure what it doesn't like about using `<datalist>`.

Comment: @aCarella Ok yeah, 2500 options seems pretty insane. I can replicate your issue in Chrome with that many results. I would make a different UI choice.

Comment: Well, at least I know I'm not going crazy. Why do you think it's not crashing with the other page I'm using this for, where it uses table rows?

Comment: @aCarella In my experience, `datalist` is very rarely used. If you google "datalist slow with many options" the first few results show people dealing with the same issue. Why it happens would be a question for the browser devs I expect.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the correct answer, but I think you're right in the comments. Datalist may not be the best thing for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @aCarella datalist issues aside, a computed property is definitely the way to go when you are trying to filter a set of values like this in Vue. Good luck :)

Comment: Just thought this through and figured it out. I keep repopulating the datalist options every time the findUser data value changes. There is no need to do that; that's what datalists do automatically. All I really needed to do was load all of my users into the datalist on page load. No need to keep repopulating it. The datalist being linked to the input box handles that automatically. Definitely overthought this. Thanks for the help.